# How can i fetch from core data using only month and day

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a core data database with people and they birthdays which is an NSDate.  I would like to fetch people that are born in february with out setting a day or a year.  Is it possible to set a predicate with specifying only month or month and day but not year, or i would have to save the dates as separate integers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please view the following for some helpful guidance pertaining to your question. It indicates that what you are asking is not directly possible, but it indicates a work-around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152512/iphone-core-data-fetching-date-manipulations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular scenario I'd add a new property, e.g. `monthDay`, to your model that saves a combination of month and day.

As Daniel already mentioned you can write a custom setter for the birthday property in your ManagedObject subclass to update `monthDay` every time the birthday gets updated.

Having this additional property makes a lot of sense to an birthday app due to performance reasons, as a `fetchRequest` would almost always have this property `monthDay` in it's `predicate`.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up creating separate integer fields for month, day and year.